# Load prefabs via script and save scene in Unity Editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I am using Unity 2019.2.6f1

I have a single scene that I am using for the main field of play. All characters are prefabs. Each level is saved to a JSON file that controls which characters are to be loaded for the scene and where they are to be positioned.

I have an editor script (SaveLevel) that will create the JSON file based on how I have the scene configured in the editor. I have a second editor script (LoadLevel) that will read the JSON file and set up the scene for that level.

This is all done in the editor at design time. I can save and load levels fine. However, after I load a level, if I hit the play button, to test the level, the scene resets to an empty scene (how it was before I loaded the level).

How can I load my prefabs into my scene and save the scene so that I can test the level?

Here is my code for loading the level:

-- EDIT --
Based on the response by @Ron the fix is the code change in `LoadLevel()` below.

```
private void LoadLevel()
{
    string path = Path.GetFullPath($"{Constants.LEVEL_FILE_PATH}{_world}-{_stage}.json");
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
    string levelJson = reader.ReadToEnd();
    Level level = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Level>(levelJson);

    var worldText = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<TextMeshProUGUI>().ToList().FirstOrDefault(t => t.tag.Equals("World"));
    var levelText = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<TextMeshProUGUI>().ToList().FirstOrDefault(t => t.tag.Equals("Stage"));
    worldText.text = _world;
    levelText.text = _stage;

    level.Bench.ForEach(b => LoadPrefab(b.TypeName, b.Position));
    level.Field.ForEach(f => LoadPrefab(f.TypeName, f.Position));

#if UNITY_EDITOR
        /// The fix is to change the 'Save' call to MarkSceneDirty() as answered by @Ron. 
        // EditorSceneManager.SaveCurrentModifiedScenesIfUserWantsTo();
        EditorSceneManager.MarkSceneDirty(EditorSceneManager.GetActiveScene());
#endif
}

private void LoadPrefab(string prefabName, Vector3Simple position)
{
    string prefabPath = $"{Constants.PREFAB_PATH}{prefabName}.prefab";
    var asset = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<GameObject>(prefabPath);
    var prefab = (GameObject)PrefabUtility.InstantiatePrefab(asset);
    prefab.transform.position = new Vector3(position.x, position.y, position.z);
    if (position.y > Constants.TOP_OF_PLAYFIELD && prefab.GetComponent<Animal>() != null)
    {
        prefab.GetComponent<Animal>().Locked = false;
    }

    AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
}
```

Here are images to show what happens:

[image: Before loading the level in the editor]

[image: After loading the level in the editor]

[image: After hitting the 'Play' button]

Comment: Are you saying that you run this code inside the editor, see the gameobjects created in the hierarchy and scene view, and when you hit play it resets to an empty scene?

Comment: Yes, except the scene's not completely empty. All of the gameobjects that are saved with the scene, before I run my script, are still there. Only the gameobjects added by my script are missing.

Comment: C# != [UnityScript](https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/UnityScript_versus_JavaScript) (which is a Javascript derivative created for unity).

Comment: @John thanks for the clarification. I added the UnityScript tag because this is a question about code not just the editor. I didn't realize that UnityScript was the official title for Unity's version of JavaScript. I've only ever used C# with Unity.

Comment: Can you please run your tool in the editor and include a screenshot of the editor + the game objects listed in the hierarchy view?

Comment: @Ron, I added three images to show what it looks like before I load the level, after I load the level, and after I click the 'Play' button.

Comment: That's really weird. And when you load, it asks if you want to save the scene and you save it? Try saving it, go to another scene and load that scene again

Comment: No, it doesn't ask about saving it. Adding the prefabs doesn't mark the scene as changed.

Comment: As a work-around, I can Load and Save in play mode. This works well enough for my purposes but it still bothers me that I can't get it working the way it should.

Comment: Can you try calling `EditorSceneManager.MarkSceneDirty(EditorSceneManager.GetActiveScene());` before you call `EditorSceneManager.SaveCurrentModifiedScenesIfUserWantsTo();`

Comment: That did it! Awesome, thank you! If you submit your comment as an answer, I'll accept it as the answer.